# Can I make android studio visual class of object like button and editext?

Tags: android, class

Do I able to create classes of **object** like Button, and then drag and drop them from palette ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to create custom `View` classes... but it's slightly more complicated to add than other views to use them in UI builder.

Comment: This is done with custom views: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom components. Please check this link, there is all details about creating custom components yourself:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html